# Exposing archive view

Tags: 6, views

I'm using an archive view which is in Views by default but just needs to be activated. It works great and is displaying the way I want it to, but I was wondering if there was an easy way for me to expose the view so I can allow users to filter content by month or within a month range (eg. from Janauary 2011 to May 2011)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Date filter. If you have the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module enabled, you can activate the Date Popup widget to allow users to easily select dates. (The popup may only work on the Page display, e.g. http://yoursite.com/archive)

Choose the 'Date: Date (node)' filter.  Set the Operator to 'Is Between' and set the value type to 'An offset from the current time'. Using your example, you can use '-4 months' for the Min value and 'now' for the Max value.

Finally, click 'Expose' to show the date filter to your users.